# Update slider value in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Originally I have a button event in code behind.

```
private async void SomeCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MySlider.Value = MySlider.Value - 1;
```

In my XAML.

```
 <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">Do Something</Button>
```

Now I am going to use MVVM.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly ICommand someCommand;
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.someCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.DoSomething, this.CanDoSomething);
    }

    public ICommand SomeCommand
    {
        get { return this.someCommand; }
    }

    private void DoSomething(object state)
    {
        // do something here
    }

    private bool CanDoSomething(object state)
    {
       // return true/false here is enabled/disable button
    }
}
```

I don't know what is the code for it inside the method `DoSomething`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use the MVVM approach you should use a property `Value` which you can bind to.
your xaml would look like

```
<Slider x:Name="MySlider" Value="{Binding Value}" />
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">Do Something</Button>
```

In an `ICommand` you use two separate methods to check if a command can be executed (`CanDoSomething`) and to execute it (`DoSomething`).

Make sure your ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` which you have to rise if `Value` changed. Your ViewModel should look like

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly ICommand someCommand;
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.someCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.DoSomething, this.CanDoSomething);
    }

    public ICommand SomeCommand
    {
        get { return this.someCommand; }
    }

    private void DoSomething(object state)
    {
        Value = Value - 1;
    }

    private bool CanDoSomething(object state)
    {
       //something like boundaries check of slider values and async is running and so on
    }

    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set 
        {
             if (_value != value)
             {
                 _value = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged(); //raise your propertyChanged event handler.
             }
        }
    }
}
```